# Which keyword can be used to replace "FROM" in SQL?

Tags: sql, security, web-application-firewall

I am trying to bypass a waf, and which keyword can be used to replace `FROM` in SQL?

Comment: If there would be a replacement keyword for FROM, it would be banned too. It's a security system, they are well aware of SQL syntax I think :-)

Answer (score 3):

`FROM` keyword specifies from which DB object (table, view, function etc) you want to fetch data and so there is no such replacement present.

So the simple and straight answer is **NO**

Comment: Thanks,another question, keyword "From" is banned. I have tried Base64 Encode,URL Encode,HexEncode,And DO NOT WORK! But "fro$m" or "f$rom" is ok. So,is there any character i can use to insert into "from",and the DBMS(MS SQL Server) can still recognize it !

Comment: @Nick, not sure what you are trying to achieve but again the answer is *NO*. Those are security holes and you can't bypass them by any means. If you try to insert a different character in between likewise you are saying, you are assured to get a compilation error.

Comment: Thanks Again.I am trying to bypass a web application firewall .The WAF will give a warning when it detects any SQL syntax in the URL.So I am trying to find any possible changing or encode  can be used for  SQL syntax and  after  changing or encode the DBMS can still execute successfully.